# Complex query using pre_get_posts

Tags: pre-get-posts

I am trying to alter the query for the `exam` custom post type in admin using `pre_get_posts`.

My scenario is that there are students and teachers roles. Every student can save their preferred teachers in a user meta `preferred_teachers_ids`.

Every post have a custom field `student_id` (student user ID).

My question is how can alter the query so every teacher can only see exams posts from the students who have added them to `preferred_teachers_ids`.

**UPDATE:**
I have created a second query to get the `student_ids`. I ended up with the following `meta_query` but is extremely slow especially the third part:

```
$meta_query = array(
  array(
    array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'key' => '_accepted_teacher',
        'compare'    => 'NOT EXISTS',
      ),
      array(
        'key' => '_accepted_teacher',
        'value' => $user_id,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare'    => '=',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'key' => '_prefered_teacher',
      'compare'    => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
    array(
      'key' => '_prefered_teacher',
      'value' => $user_id,
      'type'    => 'numeric',
      'compare'    => '=',
    ),
  ),
  array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      array(
        'key' => 'student_id',
        'value' => $student_ids,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare'    => 'IN',
      ),
      array(
        'key' => '_date_available',
        'value'   => $end_time,
        'type'    => 'DATETIME',
        'compare'    => '<',
      ),
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'student_id',
      'value' => $student_ids,
      'type'    => 'numeric',
      'compare'    => 'NOT IN',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Please be more precise and add some code, what you have tried. E.g. I wonder. Is the student the author of the `exam` post? basically, you will probably need to run two queries, one to find out, what students like the teacher and with these IDs you need to construct a `meta_query` or (prefered) an query through the authors. Something like this I guess.

Comment: No students aren't the author of the 'exam'. I tried to run a second query with 'get_users' but it was extremely slow.

Comment: Meta queries are never going to be fast, meta data was not designed for querying.